# Template specialization and inheritance template class from other template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, specialization

I have some questions about next code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Base;

template<typename T, typename P>
class Base<T(P)> {

};

template<typename T>
class Derived;

template<typename T, typename P>
class Derived<T(P)> : public Base<T(P)> {

};
```

1. Class specialization `Derived<T(P)>` inherits from class `template<typename T> class Base` or  from class `template<typename T, typename P> class Base<T(P)>`?
2. What the name of when I'm binding template parameters `T` and `P` of class specialization `Derived<T(P)>` with template parameter `T` of `class Base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Class specialization `Derived<T(P)>` inherits from class `template<typename T> class Base` or from class `template<typename T, typename P> class Base<T(P)>`?

Technically, neither. A class or class template never inherits from a template, only from one specific base class type. That is, `Derived<int(float&)>` inherits `Base<int(float&)>`, and so on. That base class gets instantiated from whatever is the most specialized declaration associated with `Base` for those specific types. The importance of this distinction comes up if there are additional partial specializations or explicit specializations.

If I change your example a bit,

```
template<typename T> // #1
class Base;

template<typename T, typename P> // #2
class Base<T(P)> {
public:
    static const int mem1 = 1;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived;

template<typename T, typename P>
class Derived<T(P)> : public Base<T(P)> {
};

class SomethingElse {};

template<typename P> // #3
class Base<SomethingElse(const P&)> {
public:
    static const long long mem2 = 2;
};

using ThingType = Derived<SomethingElse(const std::string&)>;
const auto A = ThingType::mem1; // Error!
const auto B = ThingType::mem2; // OK
```

It's not correct to say that partial specialization `Derived<T(P)>` inherits partial specialization `Base<T(P)>`, since the example type `Derived<SomethingElse(const std::string&)>` uses that `Derived` partial specialization, but doesn't use that `Base` partial specialization at all.  `Base<T(P)>` just means the template called `Base`, with whatever specialization definition for `Base` best matches the template argument `T(P)`.  The decision about what the base class `Base<T(P)>` means is made independently for each specific set of template arguments when each specialization of `Derived` is instantiated.

> 2. What the name of when I'm binding template parameters `T` and `P` of class specialization `Derived<T(P)>` with template parameter `T` of class Base.

I don't know of any term for this, other than that you are using a dependent compound type.  (Dependent = depends on one or more template parameters; Compound = the type `T(P)` involves the other types `T` and `P`.)  This also makes `Base<T(P)>` a dependent base class in the definition of `Derived<T(P)>`, meaning the compiler will not look there for plain identifiers, and you need to use `this->name` or `Base::name` to make such names valid.  It's also important that the template parameters are in "deducible contexts" within the specialization's template arguments.

Comment: Why is it so difficult? I'm writing thesis and i can't find a precise definition and explanation for such a construction.

Comment: @DarkHell I'm still not sure exactly what it is you want a term for.

Comment: I thought that such a phenomenon has a term.

Comment: First time for me to encounter the syntax like Base<T(P)> (with that "(P)"). May I ask what is a keyword to google for?

Comment: @bluk `T(P)` here is a function type. If we have the function `int f(double);`, then `Base<decltype(f)>` is the same as `Base<int(double)>`, and that type will use the partial specialization by deducing `T=int` and `P=double`.

Answer (score 2):

1. A class instantiated from the template `Derived<T(P)>` inherits from the class instantiated from `Base<T(P)>`.  Since the type `T(P)` matches your `Base` partial specialization, that template will be used to instantiate the class to inherit from.
2. It's just called inheritance.  There's nothing special going on there.  You're just instantiating the template `Base` with the type `T(P)` and inheriting from the resulting class.

---

`Base<T(P)>` will get instantiated when `Derived<T(P)>` gets instantiated, so `Derived<void(int)>` inherits from `Base<void(int)>`.  Both of those instantiations will go through the same set of rules to figure out which template to use to instantiate that class.

You may be getting confused thinking that `T(P)` is some special template thing.  It is not.  It's just the type "function that returns `T` and takes a single argument of type `P`".  Granted, types like that don't come up much outside of templates, but they're perfectly legal other places.  i.e.

```
using FuncType = void(int);

// These two declarations are exactly the same
void doAThing(FuncType* callback);
void doAThing(void(*callback)(int));
```